# jasmine TypeError: Cannot call method 'expect' of null

Tags: javascript, scope, jasmine

When I added the setTimeout I got this error for:

```
// Suite
describe("sidebar", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.fa-bars').click();
        expect(document.getElementById('sidebar')!=null).toEqual(true);
    }, 2000);

});
```

But I don't understand how calling it in a setTimeout can even trigger this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using a synchronous test to test asynchronous code. Try

```
// Suite
describe("sidebar", function() {
    runs( function(){ // encapsulates async code
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector('.fa-bars').click();
            expect(document.getElementById('sidebar')!=null).toEqual(true);
        }, 2000);
    });

});
```

For more information, check out https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs

Answer (score 1):

You need to call done callback:

```
describe("sidebar", function() {
    it('should work with setTimeout', function(done) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector('.fa-bars').click();
            expect(document.getElementById('sidebar')!=null).toEqual(true);
            done();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the preferred method as of '16.